# How to use gcov for test coverage where C programs are tested using perl scripts ?

Tags: c, perl, code-coverage, gcov

I'm currently working on gcov and I need to pointers to study gcov. Perl scripts are being used to automate testing and I need to use gcov for test coverage. Apart from the gcov documentation what are the other things I should be aware of ? How do I proceed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Devel::Cover](http://p3rl.org/cover) has gcov support.

```
cd project_root
perl Makefile.PL
cover -test -gcov
$BROWSER cover_db/coverage.html
cover -delete
```